# Flutter Live location of user in OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, flutter, maps

My team is building a Flutter app about real time bus monitoring. We are able to get the current location of the user but not when they are moving. Another problem is that we use OpenStreetMaps. Upon looking to youtube, most videos use Google Maps. I really have no idea how to code this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MapScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  LocationData _currentLocation;
  Location location = Location();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLocationPermission();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    // Uncomment the line below to enable real-time location updates
    // _startLocationUpdates();
  }

  Future<void> checkLocationPermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        // Handle the case where the user denies service enablement
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        // Handle the case where the user denies the permission
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    LocationData locationData = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      _currentLocation = locationData;
    });
  }

  void _startLocationUpdates() {
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      setState(() {
        _currentLocation = currentLocation;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Real-time Bus Monitoring'),
      ),
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(
            _currentLocation?.latitude ?? 0.0,
            _currentLocation?.longitude ?? 0.0,
          ),
          zoom: 13.0,
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
          MarkerLayerOptions(
            markers: [
              Marker(
                width: 80.0,
                height: 80.0,
                point: LatLng(
                  _currentLocation?.latitude ?? 0.0,
                  _currentLocation?.longitude ?? 0.0,
                ),
                builder: (ctx) => Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure to dispose of location subscriptions to avoid memory leaks
    location.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).